# I dont understand How does python Dash @Callback know to execute the def function

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I want understand how the @callback function knows how to execute the def update_graph, because I dont see any link where I use a variable lets say in the Input country_selector or value in the callback AND in the def function at the same time so callback knows that I want the def function to be executed. Can anyone give me simple answer for that?

```
@app.callback(
        Output('timeseries', 'figure'),
        [Input('country_selector', 'value')]
        
             )

def update_graph(selected_dropdown_value):
    
    trace = []  
    for countriesAndTerritories in selected_dropdown_value:
        #Erstelle Balkeindiagramm iterativ
        trace.append(go.Bar( 
                            x = df.month,
                            y= df[df["countriesAndTerritories"] == countriesAndTerritories] ["cases"],
                            name = countriesAndTerritories
                            ))
        
        data = trace
```

Comment: The inputs to your function correspond to the callback inputs and the return values correspond to the callback outputs. Order is important too inputs and outputs must match. In your example “selected_dropdown_value” is your “country_selector”

Answer (score 1):

A humble attempt to explain callbacks. Let's look at the first few lines :

```
@app.callback(
  Output('timeseries', 'figure'),
  [Input('country_selector', 'value')]
)
```

`@app.callback` is dash's way of reactivity of the display to a user input. It can take `inputs` and `states` of inputs and change `outputs`. So one defines all the `Output()` components that need to change (this can be a list of more than one, in that case use a `[]` to enclose all of them. Similarly, `Input` and `State` can be lists, to denote multiple inputs or states that can then effect or change the outputs.

Further, if we take a look at `Output('timeseries', 'figure')`, what we are telling dash is that we want to react the element with an `id` called `timeseries` and we want to react the `figure` element of this id. `figure` can be replaced with say `value` or `children` depending on what we are trying to change. Similar holds good for the Input and State too. First parameter depicts id of the element and second, the element that is to change.

Now, moving on to the `def` that is defined below the `@app.callback`. The name of this function is not a major factor per se, but it's parameters will now be all the inputs that we have defined earlier. In your specific example here, `def update_graph(selected_dropdown_value):`, we have one input - which is the value of `country_selector`. So `selected_dropdown_value` will now have this value.

Inside this function then, we can either call other business logic functions defined in other modules or within the dash app itself, which may take in these `inputs` and generate or return the necessary output.

An example psuedo code:

```
def generate_bar(country):
   #logic for extracting right info goes here
   scatter_fig = go.Figure()
   scatter_fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['country'], y=df['counts']
   scatter_fig.update_layout(title='new graph')
   return scatter_fig


@app.callback(
  Output('timeseries', 'figure'),
  [Input('country_selector', 'value')]
)
def update_figs(selected_dropdown_value):
   new_fig = generate_bar(selected_dropdown_value)
   return new_fig
```

Finally this `new_fig` now replaces the `figure` element having the `id` as `timeseries`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @Syamanthaka said, the call back function acts on the function definition that comes directly below it.

I understand your concern as I had the same concern especially when there are more than one function definitions in the 'code window', the functions that are not intended to be affected directly by the callback decorator are to be placed above it.

I understand that you would have preferred something like the code below to show it wraps it, sadly it does not work this way.

```
@app.callback
(
        Output('timeseries', 'figure'),
        [Input('country_selector', 'value')]
        
            

        def function_to_be_called_back(selected_dropdown_value):
    
            trace = []  
            for countriesAndTerritories in selected_dropdown_value:
                #Erstelle Balkeindiagramm iterativ
                trace.append(go.Bar( 
                                    x = df.month,
                                    y= df[df["countriesAndTerritories"] == 
        countriesAndTerritories] ["cases"],
                                    name = countriesAndTerritories
                                    ))
        
                data = trace
 )
```

Sadly, it is not designed this way. It works based on the positioning of the function definition

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an input property changes, the function that the callback decorator wraps is automatically called. The new value of the input property is provided as an input argument to the function. Dash updates the property of the output component with whatever was returned by the function.

https://www.angela1c.com/projects/dash/basic_callbacks1/